# Why no access to a memory location is given to another process?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

I have three C codes. In the first code c0.c an integer pointer (p) is dynamically allocated memory for holding one integer value. A value of 325 is assigned to the memory pointed to by this pointer variable (p). The integer value of this pointer is stored in a file. Without deallocating the memory this pointer variable (p) is assigned a NULL value. Then the integer value is read again into a long variable (i) and the pointer variable (p) is assigned the (int*) value of this variable (i). When dereferenced and printed, it prints the value 325. The code is shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  *p = 325;

  FILE *F;
  F = fopen("xxx", "w");
  fprintf(F, "%ld", (long)p);
  fclose(F);

  p = NULL;

  long i;
  F = fopen("xxx", "r");
  fscanf(F, "%ld", &i);
  p = (int*)i;
  fclose(F);

  printf("value stored in read pointer = %d\n", *p);

  return(0);
}
```

Now the same thing is tried using two separate files c1.c and c2.c. In c1.c, the pointer p is allocated memory and value 325 is stored in memory pointed to by it. The pointer's integer value is stored in a file and the program execution is paused by a scanf. In c2.c, the pointer's integer value is read and assigned to another integer pointer. This pointer variable is dereferenced and an attempt is made to print the value. An output of 325 is expected. So when c1.c is compiled and run and it comes to a pause, c2.c's compiled executable is run. It crashes. Why?

c1.c and c2.c are given below.

c1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  *p = 325;

  FILE *F;
  F = fopen("xxx", "w");
  fprintf(F, "%ld", (long)p);
  fclose(F);

  int j;
  scanf("%d", &j); // To pause the program and run c2.c executable
  return(0);
}
```

c2.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int *p;
  long i;

  FILE *F;
  F = fopen("xxx", "r");
  fscanf(F, "%ld", &i);
  p = (int*)i;
  fclose(F);

  printf("value stored in read pointer = %d\n", *p);
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: For your own protection.

Comment: Separate processes do not share memory.  You can only do this if you use shared memory.

Comment: Unclear what the actual question is. "It doesn't because isolated address spaces" seems too trivial an answer.

Comment: It is hard enough to get programs correct when there's only one of them accessing a given (physical) memory location; it becomes much harder when there are multiple programs accessing a given memory location.  You have to coordinate the access, and that takes work.  It can be done, but requires care and the use of facilities designed to make such 'inter-process communication' (IPC) possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All modern modern operating systems use virtual memory. In virtual memory each process gets its own virtual address space. The virtual address space is divided into two distinct areas: The user space and the system (or Kernel) space.

The system space is the same for all processes. However, it is not writeable from user mode and most of the addresses are not readable or executable from user mode.

The user mode address space (the part you can deal with) is unique for each process. Address 1000 in one process  normally is not the same as address 1000 in another process.

It is usually possible to create shared memory areas that can be accessed by multiple processes. However, these can be mapped to different virtual addresses. In a shared memory area, a change at address 1000
in one process may be seen at address 2000000 in another process.

When you are reading address values written by one process and try to access them in another process, the addresses are not accessible and are crashing. By inaccessible, those addresses have not yet been created in the process's virtual address space. Even if they were created, they would not be the same memory as in your other processes.

Answer (score 1):

Your operating system uses a [virtual address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) for [process isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_isolation).